# I keep reveicing the error "NameError: name 'labelAns' is not defined",

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically all I have to do is change the text on `labelAns` to a value that I insert by pressing a button, but I keep receiving an error and I don't know how I could fix it.

All I need to do now is change the label on command.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Differentiation Calculator", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Integration",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        self.num = tk.IntVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.num)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Differentiate', command=self.calc)

        labelAns = tk.Label(self,text = "0", width = 15)
        labelAns.pack(side = 'right')


        self.entry.pack(side = 'left')
        self.button.pack(side = 'left')


    def calc(self):
        Jack = (self.entry.get())

        x = sp.Symbol('x')

        res = (sp.diff(Jack,x))

        global labelAns

        labelAns(text = res)


        print(res)
```

Comment: `labelAns` is a local variable.

Comment: labelAns is defined within the scope of your class, so it's a local variable

Comment: I used "global labelAns" so it should be a global variable but it still won't work.

Comment: `global labelAns` in a different function does not magically override the fact that `labelAns` is local in the function that actually sets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is call `labelAns` global in the initial declaration of the variable. You should be able to change

```
labelAns = tk.Label(self,text = "0", width = 15)
```

into

```
global labelAns = tk.Label(self,text = "0", width = 15)
```

and it should work then. Also, you should be able to reference `labelAns` afterwards without using `global labelAns`.

Comment: it gives me a syntax error when i try to do 
 
 'global labelAns = tk.Label(self,text = "0", width = 15)'

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing something like this, so you'll have an easy reference to your label:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.labelAns = tk.Label(self,text = "0", width = 15)
        self.labelAns.pack(side = 'right')
        ...

    def calc(self):
        ...
        self.labelAns['text'] = res
        ...
```

Also notice how I changed the text for label `self.labelAns`. I don't think what you have will work--it's not something I've seen before (although it doesn't mean it wouldn't work).